# kernel panic after upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04 + 'awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub' error

Tags: 14.04, apt, 16.04, upgrade, kernel

Today I upgraded my system from 14.04 to 16.04. During the upgrade process some errors occurred in installation phase but the upgrade completion message was shown. After restarting the system and while booting up, kernel panic message was shown. So I started the system with the most recent working kernel on my machine (actually this one didn't boot up either at first, but I could get around that). Now whenever I want to use `apt-get`, the following errors are shown (particularly the message `awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub`
 is shown after running commands like `dpkg` or sometimes after pressing tab for tab completion in terminal):

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
386 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libpaper1:amd64 (1.1.24+nmu4ubuntu1) ...
awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package libpaper1:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-daemon:
 cups-daemon depends on libpaper1; however:
  Package libpaper1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up locales (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package locales (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-en-base:
 language-pack-en-base depends on locales (>= 2.3.6); however:
  Package locales is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-en:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 language-pack-en depends on language-pack-en-base (>= 1:16.04+20160627); however:
  Package language-pack-en-base is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en-base:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 language-pack-gnome-en-base depends on locales (>= 2.3.6); however:
  Package locales is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-pack-gnome-en:
 language-pack-gnome-en depends on language-pack-gnome-en-base (>= 1:16.04+20160627); however:
  Package language-pack-gnome-en-base is not configured yet.
 language-pack-gnome-en depends on language-pack-en; however:
  Package language-pack-en is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-pack-gnome-en (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up samba-common (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package samba-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of smbclient:
 smbclient depends on samba-common (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1); however:
  Package samba-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package smbclient (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up rsyslog (8.16.0-1ubuntu3) ...
awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-minimal:
 ubuntu-minimal depends on locales; however:
  Package locales is not configured yet.
 ubuntu-minimal depends on rsyslog; however:
  Package rsyslog is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up gconf2-common (3.2.6-3ubuntu6) ...
awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package gconf2-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgconf-2-4:amd64:
 libgconf-2-4:amd64 depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package gconf2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgconf-2-4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf-service-backend:
 gconf-service-backend depends on libgconf-2-4 (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gconf-service-backend depends on gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package gconf2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf-service-backend (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgconf2-4:amd64:
 libgconf2-4:amd64 depends on libgconf-2-4 (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgconf2-4:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gconf2:
 gconf2 depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
 gconf2 depends on gconf-service-backend (= 3.2.6-3ubuntu6); however:
  Package gconf-service-backend is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aisleriot:
 aisleriot depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.
 aisleriot depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package aisleriot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of alarm-clock-applet:
 alarm-clock-applet depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
 alarm-clock-applet depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package alarm-clock-applet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-terminal:
 gnome-terminal depends on libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5); however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-terminal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgs9:amd64:
 libgs9:amd64 depends on libpaper1; however:
  Package libpaper1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgs9:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript:
 ghostscript depends on libgs9 (= 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libgs9:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ghostscript (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-sag-gdi:
 printer-driver-sag-gdi depends on ghostscript; however:
  Package ghostscript is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-sag-gdi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
 cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-filters:
 cups-filters depends on ghostscript (>= 9.02~); however:
  Package ghostscript is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-filters (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on cups-core-drivers (>= 2.1.3-4); however:
  Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.
 cups depends on ghostscript (>= 9.02~); however:
  Package ghostscript is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-filters (>= 1.0.24-3~); however:
  Package cups-filters is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-gutenprint:
 printer-driver-gutenprint depends on cups (>= 1.3.0); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.
 printer-driver-gutenprint depends on cups-filters (>= 1.0.36) | ghostscript-cups (<< 9.08); however:
  Package cups-filters is not configured yet.
  Package ghostscript-cups is not installed.
  Version of ghostscript-cups on system, provided by cups-filters:amd64, is <none>.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-gutenprint (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-pxljr:
 printer-driver-pxljr depends on cups-filters (>= 1.0.42) | foomatic-filters (>= 4.0.0~bzr156); however:
  Package cups-filters is not configured yet.
  Package foomatic-filters is not installed.
  Version of foomatic-filters on system, provided by cups-filters:amd64, is <none>.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-pxljr (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-hpcups:
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups (>= 1.4.0) | cupsddk; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.
  Package cupsddk is not installed.
 printer-driver-hpcups depends on cups-filters (>= 1.0.36) | ghostscript-cups; however:
  Package cups-filters is not configured yet.
  Package ghostscript-cups is not installed.
  Package cups-filters which provides ghostscript-cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-hpcups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip:
 hplip depends on cups (>= 1.1.20); however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.
 hplip depends on printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.16.3+repack0-1); however:
  Package printer-driver-hpcups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package hplip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-postscript-hp:
 printer-driver-postscript-hp depends on hplip (>= 3.16.3+repack0-1); however:
  Package hplip is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-postscript-hp (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of printer-driver-foo2zjs:
 printer-driver-foo2zjs depends on cups-filters | foomatic-filters; however:
  Package cups-filters is not configured yet.
  Package foomatic-filters is not installed.
  Package cups-filters which provides foomatic-filters is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package printer-driver-foo2zjs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez-cups:
 bluez-cups depends on cups; however:
  Package cups is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluez-cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up udisks2 (2.1.7-1ubuntu1) ...
awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-daemons:
 gvfs-daemons depends on udisks2; however:
  Package udisks2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-daemons (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs:amd64:
 gvfs:amd64 depends on gvfs-daemons (>= 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.
 gvfs:amd64 depends on gvfs-daemons (<< 1.28.2-1ubuntu1~16.04.1.1~); however:
  Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus:
 nautilus depends on gvfs (>= 1.3.2); however:
  Package gvfs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brasero:
 brasero depends on gvfs; however:
  Package gvfs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package brasero (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-checkbox-support:
 python3-checkbox-support depends on udisks2; however:
  Package udisks2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-checkbox-support (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plainbox-provider-resource-generic:
 plainbox-provider-resource-generic depends on python3-checkbox-support (>= 0.22); however:
  Package python3-checkbox-support is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plainbox-provider-resource-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plainbox-provider-checkbox:
 plainbox-provider-checkbox depends on plainbox-provider-resource-generic (>= 0.17); however:
  Package plainbox-provider-resource-generic is not configured yet.
 plainbox-provider-checkbox depends on python3-checkbox-support (>= 0.22); however:
  Package python3-checkbox-support is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plainbox-provider-checkbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of checkbox-converged:
 checkbox-converged depends on plainbox-provider-checkbox; however:
  Package plainbox-provider-checkbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package checkbox-converged (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of checkbox-gui:
 checkbox-gui depends on checkbox-converged; however:
  Package checkbox-converged is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package checkbox-gui (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up upower (0.99.4-2ubuntu0.3) ...
awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package upower (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-power:
 indicator-power depends on upower; however:
  Package upower is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-power (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-control-center:
 unity-control-center depends on indicator-power; however:
  Package indicator-power is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unity-control-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of indicator-bluetooth:
 indicator-bluetooth depends on unity-control-center | gnome-control-center | ubuntu-system-settings; however:
  Package unity-control-center is not configured yet.
  Package gnome-control-center is not installed.
  Package ubuntu-system-settings is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package indicator-bluetooth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-json:
 php7.0-json depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-json (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-opcache:
 php7.0-opcache depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-readline:
 php7.0-readline depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-readline (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.0-cli:
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package php7.0-common is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-json; however:
  Package php7.0-json is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-opcache; however:
  Package php7.0-opcache is not configured yet.
 php7.0-cli depends on php7.0-readline; however:
  Package php7.0-readline is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.0-cli (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stoppingNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.3) ...
awk: symbol lookup error: awk: undefined symbol: mpfr_z_sub
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpaper1:amd64
 cups-daemon
 locales
 language-pack-en-base
 language-pack-en
 language-pack-gnome-en-base
 language-pack-gnome-en
 samba-common
 smbclient
 rsyslog
 ubuntu-minimal
 gconf2-common
 libgconf-2-4:amd64
 gconf-service-backend
 libgconf2-4:amd64
 gconf2
 aisleriot
 alarm-clock-applet
 gnome-terminal
 libgs9:amd64
 ghostscript
 printer-driver-sag-gdi
 cups-core-drivers
 cups-filters
 cups
 printer-driver-gutenprint
 printer-driver-pxljr
 printer-driver-hpcups
 hplip
 printer-driver-postscript-hp
 printer-driver-foo2zjs
 bluez-cups
 udisks2
 gvfs-daemons
 gvfs:amd64
 nautilus
 brasero
 python3-checkbox-support
 plainbox-provider-resource-generic
 plainbox-provider-checkbox
 checkbox-converged
 checkbox-gui
 upower
 indicator-power
 unity-control-center
 indicator-bluetooth
 php7.0-common
 php7.0-json
 php7.0-opcache
 php7.0-readline
 php7.0-cli
 initramfs-tools
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know what causes this problem. I also tried `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade` command but only `linux-headers` and `linux-image-extra` version `4.4.0-43.63` were installed and then the above message was appeared.

How can I resolve this issue? Is this related to `libpaper1` package?